# Is there something like asp.net SignalR in java?

Tags: java, asp.net, spring, spring-boot, signalr

I need to develop a chat room on web site with html and js. Is there something like asp.net SignalR in java?  It contains js client sdk and asp.net server side. it is compatible with old browser like IE8, IE9. And it will switch between long-connection and web socket by browser compatibility automatically.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe this can help ? https://github.com/SignalR/java-client

Comment: Also check https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere

Comment: signalr/java-client has already stop updating for a long time. but it seems that atmosphere is what  i want. thank you Timon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timon told me the atmosphere and I found it is suitable for me. thank you Timon very much!
https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere